# sorting mongodb field which may contain both integer and decimal?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to sort a field of mongodb which contains the numbers(non decimals and decimas). when I simply sort the decimals comes first even though they should be coming at the last. what can i do to make sorting in correct order?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some example documents and the query that doesn't result in the expected sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For following set of data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6c"), "name" : "a", "id": 0.5 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6d"), "name" : "b", "id" : 1 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6e"), "name" : "c", "id" : 1.5 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6f"), "name" : "d", "id" : 2 }
```

Following query sorts data in desc order of id.

```
db.YourCollection.find().sort({id: -1})
```

**Output**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6f"), "name" : "d", "id" : 2 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6e"), "name" : "c", "id" : 1.5 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6d"), "name" : "b", "id" : 1 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c04bb058288944d211a1a6c"), "name" : "a", "id" : 0.5 }
```

**Use** 
    `.sort({"id": 1})`
to sort data is asc.

Comment: yes that's great.. just add it to the answer so it's easier for the readers.